# Jetpack Lazy load images fade in

Tags: images, plugin-jetpack

I'm using Jetpack to lazy load images and wanted to fade in them nicely using CSS. I've tried adding the following CSS in my theme:

```
.jetpack-lazy-image {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: .3s;
    transition: .3s;
}

.jetpack-lazy-image--handled {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

but that doesn’t work. I've also tried to add this to the default WP themes, however, it doesn't work as well. Could someone please let me know what I am missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Which part doesn't work? You might need to change your transition property to include a name, as well as a delay. Optionally add the timing:

```
.jetpack-lazy-image {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition

Answer (score 0):

`.jetpack-lazy-image--handled` is added to the img before the image actually displays unfortunately. So the opacity transition happens before the image even appears. Perhaps this is a bug in Jetpack.